# Download link for video library

Tags: library, video, download

So I have a Library that I created from the Assets library template.  This will be used to upload videos to and allow users of the site to either watch them from the browser or download them.  Thing is downloaded a copy is a bit cumbersome for casual users by having them click on the check mark and then finding the "Download a copy" in the top ribbon.  Is there anyway to find that download link from sharepoint and put a hyperlink on the page that will download for them when clicked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always create your own download link, making use of the internal download application page in SharePoint. To create a link to download a video (or any other item that resides in the SharePoint), just create an good old anchor link as in my example and place in a script editor on a page.

The key that makes this work is this part that allows you to target any object to be downloaded from SharePoint.

```
/_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl=
```

An full example could look like this. Just add a script editor and copy your link there.

```
<a href='https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl=https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Shared%20Documents/BicycleSales.xlsx'>Download Document</a>
```

This works great for both On-Premise and Office 365.

Comment: Thank you.  That worked great.  It was interesting to see that i had to use the entire sharepoint link instead.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. :)

Comment: If i wanted to add that to a calculated column, I am guessing i would just add the CONCATENATE formula correct?  I think it be better to add in a link directly into the library rather then say outside the library.